# How to increase the speed of aggregating and summarizing multiple variables in R?

Tags: r, grouping, aggregate, summary

I am doing a resampling (i.e., bootstrap) procedure that involves, as one of the steps that gets repeated, calculating the mean of multiple numeric variables for each of multiple groups. I have found solutions that are pretty straight-forward using `dplyr`, `doBy`, and `data.table`, which I provide below.

However, each of them typically takes over a millisecond to complete (as per  `microbenchmark`). Since this process will be repeated several thousand times (along with other operations), I would like to optimize it as much as possible. Ideally, it would complete in microseconds or faster.

Can anyone think of a way to increase the speed of these operations? One idea I had was to convert the numeric variables to a matrix and use `colMeans()`, but wasn't sure how to do the subsetting fast.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  a = runif(1000),
  b = runif(1000),
  c = runif(1000),
  group = factor(rep(c(1, 2), 500))
)

library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise_all(mean)
#microbenchmark = 7.1 milliseconds

library(doBy)
summaryBy(. ~ group, dat, FUN = mean)
#microbenchmark = 4.6 milliseconds

library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = 'group']
#microbenchmark = 1.8 milliseconds

#base
mat <- as.matrix(dat[, 1:(ncol(dat) - 1)])
grp <- dat$group
by(mat, grp, colMeans)
#microbenchmark = 1.2 milliseconds
```

**Update:**

To provide more information about my broader task, I am creating a function that will take in data on `k` variables from `n` subjects in `g` mutually-exclusive groups in the form of a data frame (`n-by-k`). The main purpose of the function is to first aggregate the data by taking the mean of each variable within each group (`g-by-k`) and second to apply a statistical function to the mean vector for each group separately (`1-by-k`). This statistical function returns `p` estimates of parameters of interest.

Furthermore, bootstrapped confidence intervals for these estimates need to be calculated, so the function estimates these parameters for each of `r` resamples with replacement from the original data frame (stratified by group). Ultimately, I need to know the parameter estimates for each group from each resample (`p-by-g-by-r`) so that I can use percentiles or some other approach to estimate the confidence interval for each parameter in each group.

Note that I have already successfully optimized the statistical function, which now takes around 50 microseconds to complete on the most common vector size. Thus, the remaining bottleneck seems to be the creation of these vectors for each resample (i.e., the aggregating and summarizing).

Comment: Probably the solution to speeding up your code is not to speed up this specific piece, but to rethink your approach at a higher level. But you've provided far too little information for anyone to help much with that. For example, often with resampling it is faster to throw RAM at the problem and create all replicates up front in one object, and then do your grouped operations all on that.

Comment: I've added more information about the broader task; let me know if it is not clear enough. I will look into creating all the replicates up front as you suggest and will update my answer with the findings.

Comment: I suspect that going to want to write customized Rcpp code. data.table (for most things) is as fast as it gets in R and you're sweating a single millisecond, so going parallel isn't an option. Writing bare code you might make a mistake but you'll save time by excluding sanity checks etc that come with standard packages. In essence... Why do this in R to begin with?

Comment: I take a bit of that back. You're bootstrapping, so you should definitely go parallel. If your on a Mac or Linux, use fork based parallelism, e.g. mclapply and get more cores. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get to the order of microseconds using Rcpp and RcppArmadillo.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  a = runif(1000),
  b = runif(1000),
  c = runif(1000),
  group = factor(rep(c(1, 2), 500))
)
mat <- as.matrix(dat[, 1:(ncol(dat) - 1)])
grp <- as.integer(dat$group)
group_scores(mat, grp)
#microbenchmark: 48 microseconds
```

Below is the Rcpp code for the group_scores function:

```
# include <RcppArmadillo.h>
# include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat submat(NumericMatrix X, NumericVector T, int TestVal) {
  arma::mat Xmat(X.begin(), X.nrow(), X.ncol(), false);
  arma::colvec tIdx(T.begin(), T.size(), false); 
  arma::mat y = Xmat.rows(find(tIdx == TestVal));
  return y;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::rowvec col_means(arma::mat x){
  arma::mat X = arma::mat(x.begin(), x.n_rows, x.n_cols, false); 
  return arma::mean(X, 0); 
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat group_scores(NumericMatrix X, NumericVector T) {
  NumericVector levels = unique(T);
  int n = levels.size();
  int m = X.ncol();
  arma::mat out(n, m);
  for (int i(0); i < n; i++) {
    int level = levels(i);
    arma::mat sub = submat(X, T, level);
    arma::rowvec colmeans = col_means(sub);
    out.row(i) = colmeans;
  }
  return out;
}
```